# Accessing array outside of the for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to access the array soc+ out the for loop.
Outside of the for loop, it gives me only last value.
How to access whole soc array out of the for loop?

If I used append method it gives follow error
" 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' "

Thank you.

Here is part of my code

```
for k in range(1,len(t)):
    soc+=i[k]*(t[k]-t[k-1])/3600*1/(cell_capacity)
    soc = soc.append(k)
```

I tried using append method but it give the error " 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' "

Answer (score 0):

You can add break statement in the for loop and access the soc out side the for loop.
You can keep the entire for loop in 1 function and pass the range value say (k,len(t)) once come out after break.

Comment: that does not work .. simple issue but could not find how to access the entire array out of the loop .. a bit frustrating

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I replace `soc +=i[k] * (t[k] - t[k -  1]) / 3600 / (cell_capacity)` with `soc = i[k] * (t[k] - t[k - 1]) / 3600 / (cell_capacity)`.

And then do `np.cumsum.soc` outside the loop then it solves the problem for me.

It is "a" solution for me to proceed further.